# Switch statement to check if something is in an predefined aray

Tags: javascript

How do i use a switch satement to check if the number divided by a number in an array == to 0.
how ive done it befor this is by using if statements and if else stateents to check:

```
if (i % num[0] == 0) {output thingy}
if (i % num[1] == 0) {output thingy}
```

and have an array named num.

Here is my current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FizzBuzz</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="plus()">+</button>
    <button onclick="minus()">-</button>
    <button onclick="zero()">0</button>
    <h1>Number:</h1>
    <h2 id="number">0</h2>
    <h1>Value:</h1>
    <h2 id="val">0</h2>

    <script>

        var output = "";
        var val = document.getElementById("val");
        var number = document.getElementById("number");

        var i = 0;

        function zero() {
            i = 0;
            number.innerHTML = (i); 
            output = "0";
            val.innerHTML = (output);

        }

        function plus() { 
            i++; 
            thingy()
        }

        function minus() { 
            i--; 
            thingy()
        }

        function thingy() {

            var num = [3, 5]; // The numbers to multiply
            var out =  ["Fizz", "Buzz"] // The outputs

            number.innerHTML = (i);
            output = ""; 


            for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            var number = num[i];

                if (i % number == 0) {
                    switch (number[i]) {
                        case [0]:
                            output += out[0]
                            break;
                        case [1]:
                            output += out[1]
                            break; 
                }



        if ( output == "" ) { output = i; }
            val.innerHTML = (output);
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't put the value in `[]` in the case ...just `case 0` etc

Comment: It looks like it doesn't make sense to use a switch in this case. The `if` condition in the loop alone satisfies your first snippet, if you execute within it and `break;` out when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `true` as your `switch` condition.

**Example:**

```
switch (true) {
  case (i % num[0] === 0) : output code; break;
  case (i % num[1] === 0) : output code; break;
}
```

---

Also, it's worth noting that your structure here is possibly redundant:

```
if (i % number == 0) {

  switch (i) {
    
    case [0]: output += out[0]; break;
    case [1]: output += out[1]; break; 
  }
}
```

It would be enough to have:

```
if (i % number == 0) {

  output += out[i]; 
}
```